# Docker compose up error: container-linux.go: 348

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

When I typed "docker-compose up", I got  this error: 
Starting elasticsearch-1 ... error

> ERROR: for elasticsearch-1  Cannot start service elasticsearch-1:
>   b'OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting
>   container process caused "process_linux.go:402: container init caused
>   \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting
>   \\\"/c/Users/user/Desktop/data/elasticsearch.yml\\\" to rootfs
>   \\\"/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/3ec70a7ad26a47f6537aed2ac091eb2507dfb4de983183b0e669832229f948d7\\\"
>   at
>   \\\"/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/3ec70a7ad26a47f6537aed2ac091eb2507dfb4de983183b0e669832229f948d7/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml\\\"
>   caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\"": unknown: Are you trying to
>   mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified
>   host path exists and is the expected type'

Docker-compose.yml contains the following:

## From: http://blog.sandeepchivukula.com

```
elasticsearch-1:
     image: elasticsearch
     container_name: elasticsearch-1
     ports:
        - "9200:9200"
        - "9300:9300"
     volumes:
        - ./data/elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
     command: elasticsearch

kibana-frontend:
     image: kibana:latest
     container_name: kibana-frontend
     ports:
        - "5601:5601"
     links:
       - elasticsearch-1:elasticsearch
```

Could you please help me solve this error?
Any help will be appreciated
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today, and I found the solution for my case in this [GitHub Thread](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4039#issuecomment-416050850):

**Cause: I had to change my Windows password today**
Solution: The error stopped after going into Docker settings -> Shared Drives, un-selecting my drive (+ Apply), restarting Docker app and then re-selecting (+ Apply).

Kudos to danielcgithub!

Answer (score 0):

Clone (or download the ZIP) of the whole project from GIT and start the docker inside the project folder:

```
#git clone https://github.com/sandeep/photosearch/?utm_source=sandeepchivukula.com&utm_medium=blog&utm_campaign=photosearch
#cd photosearch
#docker compose up
```

Comment: I have placed the file docker-compose.yml on the destkop where I right click and choose "Git Bash Here" then I just type " docker compose up " and i get the error

Comment: After this, I notice that a new folder called "data" is created on the desktop and it contains a folder called "elasticsearch.yml" but this folder is empty

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer but  didn't understand where i should specify the folder path that you mention. Could you please help me more?

Comment: This is the link that I am following to acheive my project: https://www.google.com.lb/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://blog.sandeepchivukula.com/posts/2016/03/06/photo-search/&ved=2ahUKEwjVpozinP7cAhVF46QKHfVODjkQFjACegQICRAB&usg=AOvVaw1jIK5HnEiN4zz_ev1m-Nso&cshid=1534857238919

Comment: You need to have some file called elasticsearch.yml in your local machine... If you have not this file, then comment this 2 lines and try again... Wich docker image are you using?

 `volumes:
        - ./data/elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml `

Comment: Check the link provided by in the post: https://github.com/sandeep/photosearch/?utm_source=sandeepchivukula.com&utm_medium=blog&utm_campaign=photosearch clone it to your PC

Comment: Where I should comment the two lines you tell me about? I try it in the docker quickstart Terminal but I get: volumes: command not found

Comment: Thank you for your patience but please help me

Comment: Hello, I am following your answer, I download the zip folder and try docker compose up and it works fine :)

Comment: Thank you a lot but docker compose up is not finished and finally I get "prevMsg": "waiting for elasticsearch"

Comment: And it is still waiting , What should I do?

Comment: You can check de docker logs for debug... https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/

Comment: Hello, Is it possible to communicate with you in case I have any question?

Comment: Yesterday, I post questions on stackoverflow but no body replies

Comment: It's better if I can help you in this way, because your issue can help others too.

Comment: I am following this link to apply a photosearch project:https://github.com/sandeep/photosearch/?utm_source=sandeepchivukula.com&utm_medium=blog&utm_campaign=photosearch After running docker-compose up I get at the end the following:

Comment: kibana-frontend | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2018-08-21T15:15:14Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":9,"message":"No living connections"} kibana-frontend | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2018-08-21T15:15:14Z","tags":["status","plugin:elasticsearch@5.6.10","error"],"pid":9,"state":"red","message":"Status changed from red to red - Unable to connect to Elasticsearch at http://elasticsearch:9200.","prevState":"red","prevMsg":"Request Timeout after 3000ms"}

Comment: And it is repeated every few seconds and not finished

What should I do? Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can not bind a volume on a single file.

Either you bind the entire directory:

```
elasticsearch-1:
     image: elasticsearch
     container_name: elasticsearch-1
     ports:
        - "9200:9200"
        - "9300:9300"
     volumes:
        - ./data/:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/
     command: elasticsearch
```

Or you can use `docker configs` (see further documentation [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/configs/)):

```
elasticsearch-1:
     image: elasticsearch
     container_name: elasticsearch-1
     ports:
        - "9200:9200"
        - "9300:9300"
     configs:
        - source: elasticsearch_config
          target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
     command: elasticsearch

configs:
     elasticsearch_config:
         file: ./data/elasticsearch.yml
```